# Completed Tasks in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks

When I am in the tasks screen I can check off tasks and they will disappear.
However, if I am in the calendar view, they show up with a line through them rather than disappear. How can I change this?

Answer (score 6):

The To-Do List has a filter applied that -by default - removes tasks that have a completion date or Flag Completed Date.

[image: To-Do List Filter Dialog]

The Calendar view doesn't have the same sophisticated filter, but you can hide completed tasks.

- Go to the Calendar view.
- Right-click in the empty area below the last task.
- Select *Arrange By* and uncheck *Show Completed Tasks*.

Comment: We will try this.  Thank you very much for the response.